# Draw area/polygon and retrieve coordinates with google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there any tool that can help me with getting the coordinates for a specific area/polygon?

Comment: similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976196/box-rectangle-draw-selection-in-google-maps . If you find a solution please post here or there as answer!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use Google Earth.

Draw a polygon, then move the mouse over and right **click > copy**.

Then you can paste it in the notepad and you will find the coordinates there (remeber the format (long, lat,n) the reverse of Google Maps format.

You can also use online tools to format the information or remove parts.
http://www.earthpoint.us/Shapes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So the idea is to have a map, draw a polygon on it (I assume by placing the vertexes) and then getting the coordinates of the vertexes?

You can make markers draggable when you create then. You can also get the lat/lng position of the markers when certain events fire: the 'dragend' event, for instance.

With these tools, you have the basics of your requirements here. Make a button that places vertexes on the map - just use a marker with custom graphics - and let the user drag the vertex to whatever position they need. Record the new position of the vertex whenever the `dragend` event fires. Draw  lines on the map between the markers, to show to the user the area selected. Have a button to 'complete' the shape, linking the last vertex up with the first vertex.

There may be some existing code to do this, but I am not aware of it. However, it should be possible to throw something together with a bit of work.