# Multiple marker selection within a box in leaflet

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I need to select multiple markers in a map. Something like this: [Box/Rectangle Draw Selection in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976196/box-rectangle-draw-selection-in-google-maps) but with Leaflet and OSM.

I think it could be done by modifying the zoom box that appears when you shift click and drag in an OSM map, but I don't know how to do it.

Edit:
I rewrote the _onMouseUp function, as [L. Sanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996302/l-sanna) suggested and ended up with something like this:

```
_onMouseUp: function (e) {

    this._finish();

    var map = this._map,
    layerPoint = map.mouseEventToLayerPoint(e);

    if (this._startLayerPoint.equals(layerPoint)) { return; }

    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
    map.layerPointToLatLng(this._startLayerPoint),
    map.layerPointToLatLng(layerPoint));

    var t=0;
    var selected = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
        var a = addressPoints[i];
        pt = new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]);

        if (bounds.contains(pt) == true) {
            selected[t] = a[2];
            t++;
        }
    }

    alert(selected.join('\n'))
},
```

Comment: How did you do this exactly? Is there a way without thouching Leaflet Code? Like overriding this function?

Comment: @deckard where does the addressPoints variable that is being iterated over come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think it could be easy modificating the zoom box that appears when
>   you shift clic and drag in an osm map, but I don't know how to do it

Good idea. The zoom Box is actually a functionality of leaflet.

[Here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/54b2887667f689fa12ed1ef5fd6971f3ee8a0c58/src/map/handler/Map.BoxZoom.js) is the code.

Just rewrite the _onMouseUp function to fit your needs.

Comment: That's it, I rewrote that function and it works. I'll update my question with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried something like this?

`markers` is an array of `L.latLng() coordinates`

```
map.on("boxzoomend", function(e) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (e.boxZoomBounds.contains(markers[i].getLatLng())) {
      console.log(markers[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you add more detail about how to use this?

Comment: @Matt: There's not much to it. `markers` is just an `Array` of `L.latlng()` coordinates that when you SHIFT drag an area on the map it calls the `boxzoomend` method and shows the `markers` you've selected provided they're in the array. It's just checking to see whether the markers exist within the selected boundaries.

Comment: You have to add .getLatLng() to your marker on iteration : if (e.boxZoomBounds.contains(markers[i].getLatLng()))

Answer (score 4):

Not enough points to comment, but in order to override the _onMouseUp function like OP posted in their edit, the [leaflet tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html) gives a good explanation. Additionally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41587582/5588152) post was very helpful and walks you through every step.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but it's also possible to achieve this using the [leaflet-editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) plugin.

```
// start drawing a rectangle
 function startSelection() {
    const rect = new L.Draw.Rectangle(this.map);
    rect.enable();

   this.map.on('draw:created', (e) => {
    // the rectangle will not be added to the map unless you
    // explicitly add it as a layer
    // get the bounds of the rect and check if your points
    // are contained in it
   });
}
```

Benefits of using this method

1. Allow selection with any shape (polygon, circle, path, etc.)
2. Allow selection using a button/programmatically (does not require holding down the shift key, which may be unknown to some users).
3. Does not change the zoom box functionality