# Rewrite Leaflet event

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

I try to rewrite the boxzoom event, like this,

```
map.on('boxzoomend', function(e) {
    console.log('end')
})
```

However, the boxzoom still zoomed and I have no idea how to stop it and just print text in console. I hope to rewrite boxzoom as the following

1. Stop from zooming
2. Print text in console

Can you provide correct way to rewrite the event? Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what do you exactly want. Do you want the map to stop zoom in with mouse wheel?

Comment: Sorry for unclear. I've modified the requirement. I hope after I press shift & draw a rectangle, the map will stop from zooming & only print text in console

Comment: Actually, `map.on('boxzoomend')` mean, anything inside this function would happen once you draw the rectangle and the map finish zomming. So, the way you're trying this won't help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zooming is not performed in the `boxzoomend` event, but rather in the BoxZoom handler. Let me quote the [Leaflet source code from `src/map/handler/Map.BoxZoom.js`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.2/src/map/handler/Map.BoxZoom.js#L108):

```
_onMouseUp: function (e) {

    ...

    this._map
        .fitBounds(bounds)
        .fire('boxzoomend', {boxZoomBounds: bounds});
},
```

A better way to achieve the functionality you want is to create a new handler that extends the BoxZoom handler, modifying the methods that you need.

I recommend that you read the [Leaflet tutorials](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html), specially the ones on [creating Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html) before doing this.

The idea is to extend the BoxZoom handler:

```
L.Map.BoxPrinter = L.Map.BoxZoom.extend({
```

...modifying the _onMouseUp method...

```
    _onMouseUp: function (e) {
```

...so that instead of zooming, it just prints things:

```
        ...
        console.log(bounds);
        this._map.fire('boxzoomend', {boxZoomBounds: bounds});
   }
}
```

And as the tutorial explains, hook the handler and provide some map options for it:

```
L.Map.mergeOptions({boxPrinter: true});
L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'boxPrinter', L.Map.BoxPrinter);
```

While we're at it, disable the default BoxZoom handler for all map instances by default:

```
L.Map.mergeOptions({boxZoom: false});
```

The whole thing would look like in [this working example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/gey/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The tutorial is very helpful!

Comment: @IvanSanchez can you please reupload example i am trying to do this with Angular 7