# Rewrite react-leaflet event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a similar problem as this question from almost 7 years ago:
[Rewrite Leaflet event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582673/rewrite-leaflet-event)

Except I want to extend the `boxZoom` handler in react-leaflet.
Specifically I want to modify the `boxZoom._onMouseUp` method to use a different key and to not zoom in.

I tried modifying the MapContainer's ref, I tried using `useMap()` and `useMapEvents()` hooks.
As far as I know the MapContainer component is immutable and it uses the default Map object from 'leaflet' package, so I don't know how to replace it.