# Drawing shapes in Here Maps and affect any markers that are within shape's boundaries

Tags: google-maps, here-api

I am using the HERE Map Javascript tools and I have a map with various markers. I want users to be able to draw a shape using their mouse on the map. Any markers that are within the shape's bounds should be "touched" (i.e. updated with my prefs etc.).

I see that Google Maps users are able to do it, as in the following post: [Box/Rectangle Draw Selection in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976196/box-rectangle-draw-selection-in-google-maps)

I wonder if it's possible to do this easily using Here Maps?